# Ubuntu won't start directly on my hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu on my SSD hard drive, but to start it, I have to select Ubuntu with the <kbd>F9</kbd>/<kbd>F10</kbd> key. I partitioned and re-mounted the drive but nothing has changed. It acts just like dualboot, which I can't start directly.

Comment: Is this a gpt/uefi installation? Some uefi implementations have a hard-coded path for the startup uefi file:[root of efi partition]/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi. This can be worked around, but if you dual-boot with windows, then consider just putting up with it.

Comment: It's an old type BIOS, but I didn't manually partition the partitions myself. When it does so, ubuntu automatically groups it as follows:

dev/sda1
dev/sda2
dev/sda5

Comment: /dev/sda5 sounds like the first logical partition, within an extended partition. So then it would indeed be a non-uefi installation. But I have nothing further to suggest.